# how to search in contact list like messages application in iphone with adding selected item in front of ' To:'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I needs to make application like messages application in iphone.

Just needs To:(search text) and below it there is contact list. If user type in search text then list automatically filtered & when user select particular row then it is visible in front of To: & then again user is able to search text like in messages application.

You can see the following video http://www.apple.com/iphone/iphone-3gs/messages.html#video that shows how recipients are added one by one.

Please suggest your way for this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally make custom view for recipient & add them in recipient as like in native application.

Needs to create custom view, add it in view in scrollview. For next recipient draw the other view from current x & y position.

It is working absolutely like in native application.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write an iPhone application.

It should have a user interface with a text field in it probably with the static text "To:" in front of it and a list of contacts.  Then as people type a name into the text edit, you should write some code that filters the list based on what they have typed.